# create a alert for a specfic column

Tags: 2013, alert

I want to create a alert when a specific field is changed... I have a drop down and when the word "Eng" is chosen the person that sets the alert gets notified... how would that alert be set up?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see all changes based on a column:

- Create a view to show only those items that have that column "Eng" through a filter
- Set up an alert to use that view
- Whenever someone changes an item in that view, you should get an alert

[image]

If you want to get an alert if a specific column changes TO a value, you may have to set up a workflow or event receiver that checks to see if the value is "Eng", and send a notification if the column equals "Eng".